# Url action null object asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, url.action

I need create global url and send to email. I create global url thanks to url.action but url.action return Me null. And I don't know why. Anyone knows? 
I have method:

```
public string sendRecoveryMessage(Users userModel)
    {
        MessageModel message = new MessageModel();

        string resetLink = "<a href='"
                   + Url.Action("SetNewPassword", "Home", new { TimeLink = userModel.TimeLink }, "http")
                   + "'>Ссылка для восстановления пароля</a>";

        message.emailTo = userModel.Email;
        message.emailFrom = "Narkom@info.by";
        message.title = "Восстановление пароля";
        message.message = resetLink;

        string responseToString = SendMessage(message);

        try
        {
            RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseToString);
            return r.msg + "Для продолжения изменения пароля пройдите по ссылке указаной в письме. У вас есть сутки на изменение вашего пароля!";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return responseToString;
        }
    }
```

And route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //Defaulf route
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And recovery password method:

```
public ActionResult SetNewPassword(string TimeLink)
    {
        var recEmailDetails = dbModel.Users.Where(x => x.TimeLink == TimeLink).FirstOrDefault();

        if (recEmailDetails == null)
        {
            ViewBag.RedirectMessage = "Данная ссылка больше не активна!";
            return View("~/Views/Home/RedirectPage.cshtml");
        }

        DateTime dateNow = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        DateTime dateConfirm = Convert.ToDateTime(recEmailDetails.DateTime);

        TimeSpan diff = dateConfirm - dateNow;

        var TotalSeconds = Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);

        TotalSeconds += 86400;

        if (TotalSeconds < 0)
        {
            ViewBag.RedirectMessage = "Время действия ссылки истекло. Нам очень жаль :C";
            return View("~/Views/Home/RedirectPage.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["idResetUser"] = recEmailDetails.Id;

            ChangePasswordModel CPM = new ChangePasswordModel();

            try
            {
                recEmailDetails.DateTime = null;
                recEmailDetails.TimeLink = null;

                dbModel.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException exc)
            {
                foreach (var entityValidationErrors in exc.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        ViewBag.RedirectMessage = exc.Message;
                    }
                }
            }

            return View("~/Views/Home/SetNewPassword.cshtml", CPM);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is a "global URL"?

Comment: Because this site will be moved to the hosting and recovery link will be changed. I need dinamyc create link for access to action. Because if I write localhost:1111/SetNewPassword/TimeLink?blablabla it doesn't work in the hosting.

Comment: So? Use the current URL to grab the host name, or hardcode it in your application's configuration.

Comment: You didn't understand. I need to create link for action. I can't use your variant. And I don't know what's the server(hosting) will be in the future. This link must be universal.

Comment: I do understand. You want a link that will lead to your website. I have responded with two techniques for creating such a link.

Comment: I need to use this technique `Url.Action("About", "Home", null, "http")` => global url.

Comment: Please stop using the term "global URL" as that has no meaning.

Comment: Are you receiving email successfully? You are getting the password reset link only blank in the email?

Comment: Yes, I got email. When I used the localhost link, all was fine. But now, I have null problem. I think, maybe it's problem with route config.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
string resetLink = "<a href='" + Url.Action("SetNewPassword", "Home", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { TimeLink = userModel.TimeLink }), "http", , Request.Url.Host) + "'>Ссылка для восстановления пароля</a>";
```

Comment: Return null. :C

Answer (score 0):

Url.Action is going to render relative to the server, but not to the client reading the email.  By Global URL, you mean absolute URL, which you could just define the root URL manually like:

```
"http://somewhere.com" + Url.Action(...)
```

Which I think should render the correct URL; preview it just to be sure. If your app is a virtual directory under the root, add that to the root URL.  Also, I see the call to SendMessage; make sure nothing in there is causing the message not to render correctly (since that appears to be your custom implementation?)